# HTML / CSS - Spacing Error on Product Grid

Tags: html, css

I am working on a Flask project, but that is not too important. When I send over the result data with my rendered template I use the data and put it into a div with each product being contained in an  tag.

HTML Code

```
        <div class="products-grid">
            {% for product in products %}
                <a class="product" href="">
                    <p class="product-title line">{{ product[4] }}</p>
                    <p class="product-desc line">Description: {{ product[5] }}</p>
                    <p class="product-price line">Price: {{ product[6] }}</p>
                </a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

However, with my current CSS my positioning is off and I have no idea why, I have it so that there is 50px margins on the outer product-grid container for default but then the spacing on the side of the rightmost product is different than that of the lefmost.

CSS Code

```
.products-grid {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.product {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ce8888;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: 3%;
  padding: 5%;
}

.line {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Result of code:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:flex` for flexible items be the same length you can read [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flexbox-properties) , and if you want keep 3 box per row  carefully to set padding at `.product`

```css
.products-grid {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ce8888;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: 3%;
  /*padding: 5%;*/
}

.line {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="products-grid">
                <a class="product" href="">
                    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
                    <p class="product-desc line">Description: </p>
                    <p class="product-price line">Price: </p>
                </a>
                
                  <a class="product" href="">
                    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
                    <p class="product-desc line">Description: </p>
                    <p class="product-price line">Price: </p>
                </a>
                
                  <a class="product" href="">
                    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
                    <p class="product-desc line">Description: </p>
                    <p class="product-price line">Price: </p>
                </a>
                
                  <a class="product" href="">
                    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
                    <p class="product-desc line">Description: </p>
                    <p class="product-price line">Price: </p>
                </a>
                
                  <a class="product" href="">
                    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
                    <p class="product-desc line">Description: </p>
                    <p class="product-price line">Price: </p>
                </a>
                
                  <a class="product" href="">
                    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
                    <p class="product-desc line">Description: </p>
                    <p class="product-price line">Price: </p>
                </a>
        </div>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using `flex`. Add `text-align: center` to `.products-grid` css class.

```css
.products-grid {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.product {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ce8888;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: 3%;
  padding: 5%;
}

.line {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-grid">
  <a class="product" href="">
    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
    <p class="product-desc line">Description</p>
    <p class="product-price line">Price</p>
  </a>

  <a class="product" href="">
    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
    <p class="product-desc line">Description</p>
    <p class="product-price line">Price</p>
  </a>

  <a class="product" href="">
    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
    <p class="product-desc line">Description</p>
    <p class="product-price line">Price</p>
  </a>

  <a class="product" href="">
    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
    <p class="product-desc line">Description</p>
    <p class="product-price line">Price</p>
  </a>

  <a class="product" href="">
    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
    <p class="product-desc line">Description</p>
    <p class="product-price line">Price</p>
  </a>

  <a class="product" href="">
    <p class="product-title line">Product</p>
    <p class="product-desc line">Description</p>
    <p class="product-price line">Price</p>
  </a>
</div>
```